# Interactive SVG / control through links

Tags: jquery, html, svg, d3.js, interactive

As I'm just entering SVG (never used this before) i have few questions concerning manipulating svg object.

http://pastebin.com/VTXLwJrq

This is an image of a bicycle, nothing special. Some parts has got own ID like (tyres, frame, fork etc.).

What I want to achieve? Two goals:
+ manipulate color (fill or stroke; item depend) through links ()
+ make some part of svg selectable.

Mechanism:
+ User click on specific part of svg, e.g. on tyre (select item to change),
+ then he click on a hyperlink which will change its color for e.g. red

It wont work when I add a link before each svg elemnt (inside) so I assume I need to do it through jquery. is there any documentation which explain that? or rather I should focus on some kind of JS library like Raphael or other?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, your lucky day as I'm not busy right now so I have time to hard code this for you.
[SEE WORKING DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/HEC2Z/)

You can definitely controlling the color using JQuery, or even standard css. The demo used JQuery and UI. I also left a hover sample in pure css for the inner circle of the tyres.

```
#felgi:hover circle {
    stroke: green;
    fill: silver;
}
```

Comment: You are quite welcome. Mind select this as the answer if it works for you?

Comment: only one question - what if I would like to add several condiotions into that function? when i added other items, after one click the color changes in all elements :O

Comment: Two things to do: 1. Warp the object you would like to make clickable with <a href="#" class="svg">. You can change the class name as you wish but remember to change the js code accordingly. 2. In the js code  $("#opony circle").css("stroke",this.id); it selects what object to be affected, in this example is the circle path within item #opony.

Comment: Im not sure If i were precise enough - could you take a look on: http://jsfiddle.net/HEC2Z/4/ 

when I want to change tire & rim color. But when I click on specific element, and change color - color change for both elements.

Comment: That's because you are using the same id#dialog for function $( "#dialog button" ).click(function() {... IDs must be unique. Use two different you will be okay.